# app.appContext.config.globalProperties undefined in unit tests using jest, vue 3 and quasar v2

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vuex, vuejs3, quasar-framework

I have the very simple test below:

```
import { describe, expect, it } from "@jest/globals";
import { installQuasarPlugin } from "@quasar/quasar-app-extension-testing-unit-jest";
import { mount, shallowMount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import App from "../../../src/App.vue";

installQuasarPlugin();

describe("App", () => {
  it("sets the correct default data", () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(App);

    const { vm } = wrapper;

    expect(typeof vm.$q).toBe("object");
    expect(typeof vm.app).toBe("object");
    // expect(vm.counter).toBe(0);
  });
});
```

And in my App component:

```
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  setup() {
    const app = getCurrentInstance();
    const $q = useQuasar();
    if (
      app.appContext.config.globalProperties.$securityUtils.isAuthenticated()
    ) {
      const configuracoes = JSON.parse(store.getters["auth/configuracoes"]);
      app.appContext.config.globalProperties.$axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `${app.appContext.config.globalProperties.$securityUtils.getTipoToken()} ${app.appContext.config.globalProperties.$securityUtils.getToken()}`;
      $q.dark.set(
        configuracoes.TEMA ==
          app.appContext.config.globalProperties.$enums.theme.DARK
      );
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Apparently jest can't understand how globalProperties are getCurrentInstance and returns the following error to me:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'isAuthenticated' of undefined

      20 |     const $q = useQuasar();
      21 |     if (
    > 22 |       app.appContext.config.globalProperties.$securityUtils.isAuthenticated()
```

I am sorry for my english.